# phpseclib 2 RSA decryption works fine but phpseclib 3 RSA decryption not work properly

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

**phpseclib2 sample** - **working**

```
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
$rsa = new RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($PRIVATE_KEY);
$key = $rsa->decrypt(base64_decode($a));
```

**phpseclib3 sample** - **not working**

```
use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;

$private = PublicKeyLoader::load($PRIVATE_KEY);
$key = $private->decrypt(base64_decode($a));
```

Comment: If you could post `$PRIVATE_KEY` and `$a` that'd make it waaaaay easier to figure this out. But in lieu of that...  do `echo $private;` just to make sure the key loaded correctly. Is it a public or private key? phpseclib3 only decrypts with private keys whereas phpseclib2 could do so with both. Then do `echo $private->getLength();` and `echo strlen(base64_decode($a))` and post the results. https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib2_compat/blob/master/src/Crypt/RSA.php#L865 kinda hints at some of the changes between phpseclib2 and phpseclib3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both V2 and V3 use OAEP by default for RSA, but V2 uses SHA1 as the default for the OAEP and MGF1 digest, while V3 uses SHA256 (s. [here](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/2.0/examples.html#encrypt,pkcs1,pkcs1pub,sign1,enc1,1.0,) and [here](https://phpseclib.com/docs/rsa#rsaencryption_oaep)).
So in order for a decryption that works with V2 to also work with V3, the digests in V3 must be explicitly set to SHA1:

```php
$decrypted = $private->withHash("sha1")->withMGFHash("sha1")->decrypt(base64_decode($a));
```

Note that SHA1 is considered insecure, but there are no known security issues in the context of OAEP, see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/112032) for more details.
However, there is no reason not to switch to SHA256 (as far as possible), if only to support the elimination of SHA1 from the ecosystem.